# Disponibilizar componentes React como dependencia

Tags: javascript, react, ecmascript-6, componentes

blz?
eu tenho alguns componentes react aqui e preciso disponibilizar todos eles em uma dependência so, estilo o semantic,
como posso fazer isso?

eu estou tentando exporta os componentes em um index que importa e exporta tudo
mas eu estou tendo um problema

no projeto que usa a dependência dos componentes, o js que chega não vem transpilado

ex: no projeto com os componentes eu faço um index e importo os componentes assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[imagem 1]

no projeto que usa a dependência eu importo os componentes, mas se eu mandar da um build ele da esse erro

[imagem 2]

caso eu não de um build e mande da start de uma vez, o projeto sob mas da um erro no js do navegado pq o js dos componentes estão vindo como es6

[imagem 3]

alguem sab oq pode ser? e como resolver?

obs: desculpa a imagem, não posso colocar mais de 1 link

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa compilar sua lib antes de utiliza-la, essa é a melhor forma de reaproveitar seus componentes em outro projeto.

Sabendo disso, agora a pergunta que fica é, como fazer?

Se você estiver usando [Webpack](http://webpack.js.org), continue usando ele, mas se atente as mudanças que você precisa fazer para **publicar seu projeto como uma library**, recomendo seguir a própria documentação do Webpack para que você consiga fazer isso no seu projeto:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx

Caso não esteja usando Webpack, recomendo usa-lo ou então, usar o [Rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org) que é uma solução criada especialmente para este fim.

Um detalhe importante para você se apegar é sobre os *stylesheets*. Tente extrai-los em um arquivo `.css` separado, se você não o fizer, os estilos dos seus componentes serão embarcados juntos com a lógica (script), o que vai implicar em perca de performance e visualmente vai parecer estranho também.